# Keras Model Dense Input Shape Throwing Error

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I have a feature vector with shape `X_train.shape` as `(52, 54)`

When I train the keras model It throws me the error as:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected dense_109_input to have shape (None, 52) but got array with shape (52, 54)
```

I have tried almost everything I can think of as well as scanned stack overflow but my problem still persists. Code is as:

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

##### Reading CSV #####  
data = pd.read_csv('Dataset/Emotion_data.csv')

X = data.ix[:, 4:]
y = data['label']

##### Normalizing #####
featureName = list(X)
for name in featureName:
    X[name] = (X[name] - min(X[name]))/(max(X[name]) - min(X[name]))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=3)

##### Model #####
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(100, input_shape=(54,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, prediction))
```

If someone is interested in data head

```
In[42]: X_train.head()
Out[42]: 
       tempo  total_beats  average_beats  chroma_stft_mean  chroma_stft_std  \
35  0.438961     0.480897       0.505383          0.504320         0.938452   
34  0.520000     0.552580       0.500670          0.581778         0.680247   
63  0.477551     0.361328       0.334990          0.705472         0.357676   
27  0.477551     0.345419       0.309433          0.492245         0.728405   
43  0.520000     0.530305       0.495715          0.306097         0.663995   

    chroma_stft_var  chroma_cq_mean  chroma_cq_std  chroma_cq_var  \
35         0.932494        0.975206       0.394472       0.366960   
34         0.657810        0.654770       0.550766       0.522269   
63         0.333977        0.495473       0.618748       0.591578   
27         0.707998        0.644147       0.628125       0.601222   
43         0.640980        0.591299       0.639918       0.613379   

    chroma_cens_mean    ...       zcr_var  harm_mean  harm_std  harm_var  \
35          0.964034    ...      0.381363   0.021468  0.426776  0.225840   
34          0.755071    ...      0.213207   0.021598  0.115191  0.031476   
63          0.704930    ...      0.197960   0.021620  0.350194  0.163286   
27          0.715832    ...      0.247092   0.022253  0.319208  0.140714   
43          0.784991    ...      0.221276   0.021777  0.656981  0.471881   

    perc_mean  perc_std  perc_var  frame_mean  frame_std  frame_var  
35   0.362241  0.673257  0.467421    0.343459   0.174215   0.048846  
34   0.365434  0.152561  0.031588    0.091940   0.088991   0.018342  
63   0.340043  0.320664  0.116833    0.097610   0.077334   0.015154  
27   0.372315  0.604247  0.380492    0.995443   1.000000   1.000000  
43   0.377154  0.529161  0.296033    0.122519   0.089255   0.018417  

[5 rows x 54 columns]
```

Comment: on a side note, assign value/object to a "keras" variable may be a not that good idea.

Comment: @edouard thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define your input shape correctly in the first layer

```
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape=(54,), activation='relu'))
```

Try changing the code in your first layer to

```
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape=(52, 54), activation'relu))
```